# Python - Remove comma of last object in a string for valid JSON

Tags: python, json, regex

I'm facing some difficulties while trying to figure it out, what it the optimal way to convert a string to a valid JSON, using Python.

Basically, what I need to do is to read a string (which is already given in a JSON format) from a file, and convert it to a valid JSON. The only problem in my case, is the " , " after the last object:

```
    {
        "InputTable" : 
        [
            {
                "ServerName":"serverOne",
                "To":"userOne", 
                "CC":"", 
                "TemplateName":"LinuxTemplate" 
            },
            {
                "ServerName":"serverTwo",
                "To":"userTwo", 
                "CC":"userFive", 
                "TemplateName":"LinuxTemplateWithCC" 

            }, << get rid of this comma

        ],
        "Params": 
        [   

            {"Col_0":"Server","Col_1":"User","Col_2":"Action"}
        ]
    }
```

This is how I read the file:

```
with open('/nfs/somePath/LinuxInput.JSON') as json_file:  
        try:
            jsonFormatInputTable = json.load(json_file)
        except:
            print ("Couldn't read JSON file, cancled operation.")
            return
```

Loading the JSON file fails because the JSON is not valid.
Do you have any suggestion, first how to get rid of that last comma, and second how to validate the string and make sure it is in the correct format?

Comment: Why isn't it valid JSON to begin with? If this is a one-time thing… just delete it manually. If some other program is producing that "JSON", *it* needs to be fixed to produce *valid* JSON.

Comment: Unless you want to write a complicated regex to parse it, better fix the problem at source where the json is produced

Comment: try parsing using [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, it's not that complicated: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1392736/178988

Answer (score 12):

You could parse it as YAML (whose in-line syntax is a more permissive superset of JSON):

```
import yaml
data = yaml.load(open(json_file))
```

then to get valid JSON back you can dump the object back out:

```
import json
json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: Now that is a hack if I've ever seen one.

Comment: @deceze it seems like a pretty robust solution to me. valid json is still handled correctly (this is a requirement for yaml) and invalid json is handled better.

Answer (score 3):

If your JSON is valid except for the trailing commas, you can try using more relaxed parsers like the other solution said.

If you just want to remove the trailing commas, this regex should work.

```regex
(?<=[}\]"']),(?!\s*[{["'])
```

Replace all occurrences with an empty string.

```python
import re
regex = r'''(?<=[}\]"']),(?!\s*[{["'])'''
result = re.sub(regex, "", test_str, 0)
```

Comment: This replacement can damage strings. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1392736/178988

Answer (score 2):

You could using jsoncomment https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsoncomment

```
import json
from jsoncomment import JsonComment

with open('/nfs/somePath/LinuxInput.JSON') as json_file:    
    parser = JsonComment(json)
    data = parser.load(json_file)
```

Answer (score -2):

There You go:

=^..^=

```
test_string = """{
    "InputTable" : 
    [
        {
            "ServerName":"serverOne",
            "To":"userOne", 
            "CC":"", 
            "TemplateName":"LinuxTemplate" 
        },
        {
            "ServerName":"serverTwo",
            "To":"userTwo", 
            "CC":"userFive", 
            "TemplateName":"LinuxTemplateWithCC" 

        },

    ],
    "Params": 
    [   

        {"Col_0":"Server","Col_1":"User","Col_2":"Action"}
    ]
}"""

test_string = re.sub("},\n\n", "}\n", test_string)
valid_jonson = json.loads(test_string)
```