# Lenient JSON Parser for Python

Tags: python, json

Is there a "lenient" JSON Parser for Python?

I keep getting (handwritten) JSON files such as this:

```js
/* This JSON file is created by someone who does not know JSON
   And not competent enough to search about "JSON Validators" */

{

  /* Hey look!
     A honkin' block comment here!
     Yeehaw */

  "key1": "value1",  // Hey look there's a standard-breaking comment here!
  "key3": .65,       // I'm too lazy to type "0"
  "key4": -.75,      // That "other" .Net program works anyways...
  "key5": [ 1 /* One */, 2 /* Two */, 3 /* Three */, 4 /* Four */],
  "key2": "value2",  // Whoopsie, forgot to delete the comma here...
}
```

The program that actually consumed those monstrously malformed JSON files *somehow* doesn't puke on those errors. That program is written using C#, by the way.

I'm writing some scripts in Python that will perform things based on those JSON files, but it keeps crashing (correctly) on those mistakes.

I *can* manually edit those .json files to be standard-compliant... but there are a LOT of them and thus it's too effort-intensive -- not to mention that I will have to keep editing new incoming JSON files, urgh.

So, back to my question, is there a ***lenient*** JSON parser that can consume those malformed JSON files without dying?

**Note:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56592689/python-remove-comma-of-last-object-in-a-string-for-valid-json) concerns only trailing comma of last object; it does NOT handle block-comments and/or inline comments.

---

**Edit:** What the... I just received a JSON file in which the creator decided to remove leading zero for 0 < numbers < 1 ... -_-

And I discovered a file where the comment is embedded... :fuming_red:

I'll update the example above to reflect my additional "findings"...

Comment: this [gist](https://gist.github.com/liftoff/ee7b81659673eca23cd9fc0d8b8e68b7) might help or if you just want to use library use [jsoncomment](https://pypi.org/project/jsoncomment/)

Comment: The [commentjson](https://commentjson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library might help

Comment: @warl0ck that's an ugly regex... O_o

Comment: @GalAbra according to the documentation, it does not seem to handle `/* ... */` block comments, so I don't think it will help.

Comment: @pepoluan I am aware, just suggested in case u might want to write instead of using a library. PS: its not my gist, I know this as i have used it in past in one of my project

Comment: @warl0ck ahaha, I understand... it's just that seeing a hypercomplex regex brings back memories of regex debugging, something I really am not looking forward to :sweat_smile: ... but I agree, it gives the idea that I should write my own "preparser". Thanks!

Comment: Basically, you want to parse something which does not adhere to any standards and may or may not resemble some subset of Javascript… Good luck with that. This is really something that needs to be fixed on the producer side. If it can't be fixed there, well… FML, or FYL I guess.

Comment: @deceze if I have any influence over the producers, I would've exerted my influence over them. Unfortunately, I don't, so I have to resort to fixing things up on my side. Not a fun effort, definitely. \*shrugs\* as long as I get paid... :D

Comment: @deceze it makes me wonder, though... what kind of godforsaken .Net library dare to accept this unholy mangling of JSON as a valid input??

Comment: `node -e "console.log(JSON.stringify($json));"`…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so @warl0ck's comment made me think that I might be better off writing my own **"JSON Preprocessor"** to do the heavy-duty cleanup.

So, [here it is in my **BitBucket Snippet**](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/pepoluan/6Aj9bz), complete with a simple unit test.

I've tested it with my corpus of human-generated malformed JSON files, and it *seems* to work well so far...

Let me know if there's a bug in there code.

But for the time being, I'm content.

---

**EDIT:** Because BitBucket deleted all my snippets, I reupload the code to GitHub: https://gist.github.com/pepoluan/361724bfa5cce9d863dadc6e2bdcb8c9

Comment: glad could be of help

Comment: That repo no longer exists.

Comment: @Anm I'll try to reupload the preprocessor when I get back home.

Comment: @Anm I've reuploaded the code to my Gist. Sorry it took so long to do; I have to re-find the code first.