# AJAX web scraping using python Requests

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, python-requests

I was trying to scrape [this website](https://www.assetmanagement.hsbc.de/de/institutional-investors/fund-centre?f=Yes&n=-1&v=Documents) but was'nt getting the table data. I even got the request data from the Chrome dev tools but I cannot find out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my script:

```
import requests,json
url='https://www.assetmanagement.hsbc.de/api/v1/nav/funds'
payload={"appliedFilters":[[{"active":True,"id":"Yes"}]],"paging":{"fundsPerPage":-1,"currentPage":1},"view":"Documents","searchTerm":[],"selectedValues":[],"pageInformation":{"country":"DE","language":"DE","investorType":"INST","tokenIssue":{"url":"/api/v1/token/issue"},"dataUrl":{"url":"/api/v1/nav/funds","id":"e0FFNDg5MTJELUFEMzEtNEQ5RC04MzA4LTdBQzZERTgyQTc4Rn0="},"shareClassUrl":{"url":"/api/v1/nav/shareclass","id":"ezUxODdjODJiLWY1YmItNDIzOC1hM2Y0LWY5NzZlY2JmMTU3OX0="},"filterUrl":{"url":"/api/v1/nav/filters","id":"ezRFREYxQTU3LTVENkYtNDBDRC1CMjJDLTQ0NDc4Nzc1NTlFQn0="},"presentationUrl":{"url":"/api/v1/nav/presentation","id":"e0E1NEZDODZGLUE5MDctNDUzQi04RTYyLTIxNDNBMEM1MEVGQ30="},"liveDataUrl":{"id":"ezlEMjA2MDk5LUNCRTItNENGMy1BRThBLUM0RTMwMEIzMjlDQ30="},"fundDetailPageUrl":"/de/institutional-investors/fund-centre","forceHttps":True}}
headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36"}
r = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=payload)
print(r.content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it lacked initially the `IFC-Cache-Header` http header in the first place, there is also a JWT token that is passed via `Authorization` header.

To retrieve this token, you first need to extract values from the root page :

```
GET https://www.assetmanagement.hsbc.de/de/institutional-investors/fund-centre
```

which features the following javacript object:

```js
window.HSBC.dpas = {
    "pageInformation": {
        "country": "X", <========= HERE
        "language": "X", <========= HERE
        "tokenIssue": {
            "url": "/api/v1/token/issue",
        },
        "dataUrl": {
            "url": "/api/v1/nav/funds",
            "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" <========= HERE
        },
        ....
    }
}
```

You can extract the `window.HSBC.dpas` javascript object value using regex and then reformat the string so that it becomes valid JSON

These values are then passed in http headers such as `X-COUNTRY`, `X-COMPONENT` and `X-LANGUAGE` to the following call:

```
GET https://www.assetmanagement.hsbc.de/api/v1/token/issue
```

It returns the JWT token directly and add the `Authorization` header to the request as `Authorization: Bearer {token}`:

```
GET https://www.assetmanagement.hsbc.de/api/v1/nav/funds
```

Example:

```py
import requests
import re
import json

api_url = "https://www.assetmanagement.hsbc.de/api/v1"
funds_url=f"{api_url}/nav/funds"
token_url = f"{api_url}/token/issue"

# call the /fund-centre url to get the documentID value in the javascript
url = "https://www.assetmanagement.hsbc.de/de/institutional-investors/fund-centre?f=Yes&n=-1&v=Documents"
r = requests.get(url,
params = {
    "f":"Yes",
    "n": "-1",
    "v": "Documents"
})
# this gets the javascript object
res = re.search(r"^.*window\.HSBC\.dpas\s*=\s*([^;]*);", r.text, re.DOTALL)
group = res.group(1)

# convert to valid JSON: remove trailing commas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56595068 (added "e")
regex = r'''(?<=[}\]"'e]),(?!\s*[{["'])'''
result_json = re.sub(regex, "", group, 0)

result = json.loads(result_json)
print(result["pageInformation"]["dataUrl"])

# call /token/issue API to get a token
r = requests.post(token_url,
headers= {
    "X-Country": result["pageInformation"]["country"],
    "X-Component": result["pageInformation"]["dataUrl"]["id"],
    "X-Language": result["pageInformation"]["language"]
}, data={})
token = r.text
print(token)

# call /nav/funds API
payload={
    "appliedFilters":[[{"active":True,"id":"Yes"}]],
    "paging":{"fundsPerPage":-1,"currentPage":1},
    "view":"Documents",
    "searchTerm":[],
    "selectedValues":[],
    "pageInformation": result["pageInformation"]
}
headers={
    "IFC-Cache-Header": "de,de,inst,documents,yes,1,n-1",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
}
r = requests.post(funds_url,headers=headers,json=payload)
print(r.content)
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://replit.com/@bertrandmartel/HSBCFundCentre)

Comment: Can you kindly guide me how you figured that out?

Comment: @ImranaJabeen Sure, you can open the chrome development console and go to network tabs, pick up the api call and right click "copy as curl" then execute the command in a terminal, try to remove some headers and you can narrow down the requirements

Comment: After running the code a few time it stops working. Like now it returns an incomplete html.

Comment: @ImranaJabeen please see updated post above